# What's the preferred method for accessing settings information in Django?

Tags: python, django

Please chime in if there are other methods but the ones I see most often are these two and they both exist in the django source.

`if settings.DEBUG:`

and

`if hasattr(settings, 'POSTGIS_VERSION'):`

The later has the advantage of having a default but in cases where a default would be an error (something is missing) is it better to use the first version? What's the rule on defaults, when should you put it in the settings.py file and when should you include it directly in the source like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a setting defined by your app in your apps' defaults, I'd suggest `if settings.name:` - the default is defined by you already. On the other hand, when writing an external app - I'd suggest `if hasattr(settings, 'name'):` - you can't expect your apps users will define all the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the first answer. Quite reliable and readable way to get something from Django:

```
variable = getattr(settings, 'MY_SETTING', None)
```

Now variable equals some setting or None, if there was no such setting at all.